# Docker GitLab backups in Azure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to get backups running via docker.

So I've 2 containers running:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED       STATUS                 PORTS
                NAMES
797e3c6818a7   gitlab/gitlab-runner:latest    "/usr/bin/dumb-init …"   2 hours ago   Up 2 hours
                gitlab-runner
ba53133df54b   gitlab/gitlab-ee:16.5.1-ee.0   "/assets/wrapper"        2 hours ago   Up 2 hours (healthy)   80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8***->8***/tcp, 0.0.0.0:2224->22/tcp   gitlab-ee
```

After setting up some dummy data I tested the backups and they seem to have worked.

I followed this article https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/backup_restore/backup_gitlab.html#using-azure-blob-storage to try and set it up for Azure, with:

```rb
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection'] = {
 'provider' => 'AzureRM',
 'azure_storage_account_name' => 'sac********',
 'azure_storage_access_key' => 'o*****************************************==',
 'azure_storage_domain' => 'blob.core.windows.net', # Optional
}
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = 'https://sac*********.blob.core.windows.net/backups'
```

and it keeps on failing with:

```
Caused by:
Azure::Core::Http::HTTPError: InvalidResourceName (400): The specifed resource name contains invalid characters.
RequestId:4f4cf6cf-a01e-0000-5e5d-334f7f000000
Time:2023-12-20T16:02:50.9411709Z
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:345:in `upload'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:234:in `run_all_create_tasks'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/backup/manager.rb:47:in `create'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:13:in `block in create_backup'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:62:in `lock_backup'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:10:in `create_backup'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/backup.rake:101:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:25:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:backup:create
```

I've checked the storage name which met up with the following article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/naming-and-referencing-containers--blobs--and-metadata

Comment: Based on my reading of the docs, I think `gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory']` should just be the container path, e.g., the portion of the URI _after_ `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/...` and not the full URI. That is to say, if your container URI is `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer` then the value of `backup_upload_remote_directory` should just be `mycontainer` (and I would say the documentation could use improvement in making it clear what the value should be in the case of Azure Blob) I think it could also be the blob path like `mycontainer/myblob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory']` should just be the continaer/blob path, **not the full URI**. The URI is formed dynamically from your other parameters like `https://{azure_storage_account_name}.{azure_storage_domain}/{backup_upload_remote_directory}`

For example, if you want the destination to be `https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer` you should configure the settings like so:

```rb
gitlab_rails['backup_upload_connection'] = {
 'provider' => 'AzureRM',
 'azure_storage_account_name' => 'myaccount',
 'azure_storage_access_key' => '****',
 'azure_storage_domain' => 'blob.core.windows.net', # Optional
}

gitlab_rails['backup_upload_remote_directory'] = 'mycontainer'
```

---

By implementation detail, GitLab uses a third party gem called Fog (specifically [fog-azure-rm](https://github.com/fog/fog-azure-rm) for Azure) for abstracting the interaction with remote object storage of various cloud providers. A [connection is created](https://github.com/fog/fog-azure-rm/blob/master/lib/fog/azurerm/docs/storage.md#create-connection) using the `backup_upload_connection` settings. Subsequently, the `backup_upload_remote_directory` value is used in the file objects that Fog [uses to dynamically create the URI](https://github.com/fog/fog-azure-rm/blob/68ea3f7dd14c0a524146f1e426fa2ad1f6192cc8/lib/fog/azurerm/utilities/general.rb#L125) using the path plus connection details.